# SQL insert statement is not inserting values in database from Jupyter notebook( Anaconda)

Tags: mysql, sql, jupyter-notebook

I have some problem inserting data in MySQL. The program is running without any errors but the values are not getting inserted. Below is the code. I doubt there is some mistake in format specifiers.The python version I am using is 3.5.3. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import MySQLdb 

# Open database connection 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pwd","project") 

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method 
cursor = db.cursor() 

add_metric = ("INSERT INTO metrics "  "(clicks, pageviews, sessions, source, browser,device_type)"
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s)")

data_metric = (5,6,7,'s','a','f')

cursor.execute(add_metric, data_metric)

cursor.close();

db.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you have to commit your connection or set autoCommit to true

> db.autocommit(True);

or

> db.commit(); before closing the cursor